# How to access value calculated in `useEffect` hook from renderer

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am developing a React-Native project with functional component.

Here is a very simple screen which renders a calculated result list. Since I need to calculation to be called only once so I put it inside the `useEffect` hook.

```
import {doCalculation} from '../util/helper'

const MyScreen = ({navigation}) => {
   useEffect(() => {
     // I call a function from a helper module here. 
     // The result is a list of object.
     const result = doCalculation();

     // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  // renderer
  return (
      <View> 
        // Problem is 'result' is not accessible here, but I need to render it here
        {result.map(item=> <Text key={item.id}> {item.value} </Text>)}
      </View>
  )
}

export default MyScreen;
```

As you can see I have called the `doCalculation()` to get the `result` inside `useEffect` hook. My question is how can I render the result in the `return` part? Since the `result` is calculated inside the hook, it is not accessible in the renderer.

P.S. Moving the `const result = doCalculation()` outside the `useEffect` hook is not an option since I need the calculation to be called only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example.  According to the above comments it looks like you want it to be called once on component mount.  All you really need to do is add a `useState`

```
import {doCalculation} from '../util/helper'

const MyScreen = ({navigation}) => {
   const [calculatedData, setCalculatedData] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
     // I call a function from a helper module here. 
     // The result is a list of object.
     const result = doCalculation();
     setCalculatedData(result)

     // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  // renderer
  return (
      <View> 
        // Problem is 'result' is not accessible here, but I need to render it here
        {calculatedData.map(item=> <Text key={item.id}> {item.value} </Text>)}
      </View>
  )
}

export default MyScreen;
```

```
   const [calculatedData, setCalculatedData] = useState([])
```

`useState` is a hook used to store variable state.  When calling `setCalculatedData` inside the `useEffect` with empty dependency array it will act similar to a `componentDidMount()` and run only on first mount.  If you add variables to the dependency array it will re-run every-time one of those dep. change.

You can change the data inside the `calculatedData` at anytime by calling `setCalculatedData` with input data to change to.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `useState` to save the calculation result and then use the variable inside `return`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html.

Comment: Could you please provide code snippet, since I am not sure how to `useState` while having to have the calculation only be called once, which means I have to put it inside `useEffect` hook. I don't think I can `useState` inside `useEffect` hook.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-firefly-2sq2m?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
import {doCalculation} from '../util/helper'

const MyScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     // I call a function from a helper module here. 
     // The result is a list of object.
     const tempRes = doCalculation();
     setResult(tempRes);

     // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  // renderer
  return (
      <View> 
        // Problem is 'result' is not accessible here, but I need to render it here
        {result.map(item=> <Text key={item.id}> {item.value} </Text>)}
      </View>
  )
}

export default MyScreen;
```

Comment: This will recalculate every time

Comment: Care to expain why?

Comment: If he adds additional logic to the component that causes it to re-render then your `useEffect` hook is going to be called every time it re-renders

Comment: I'm afraid you're mixing up component rerenders and component mounts, the `useEffect` in my answer is only gonna be run once, on Mount, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

### Is async function?

if the function is not async (not wating for respond like from api) - you don't need useEffect.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {doCalculation} from '../util/helper'

const results = doCalculation();

const MyScreen = () => {

  return (
      <View> 
        {results.map(item=> <Text key={item.id}> {item.value} </Text>)}
      </View>
  )
}

export default MyScreen;
```

> else you should wait until the results come from the server..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { doCalculation } from '../util/helper';

const MyScreen = () => {

  const [results, setResults] = useState(null) // or empty array

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setResults(await doCalculation());
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {results?.map(item => <Text key={item.id}> {item.value} </Text>) || "Loading..."}
    </View>
  )
}

export default MyScreen;
```

and I can use more readable code:

```
  if (!results) {
    return <View>Loading...</View>
  }
  return (
    <View>
      {results.map(item => <Text key={item.id}> {item.value} </Text>)}
    </View>
  )
```

the async function can be like:

```
const doCalculation = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([{ id: 1, value: 1 }]);
    }, 2000);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. My function is not a API call but just a local calculation logic. It would mean the 1st code snippet in your answer. So, do you mean by calling that function outside the `MyScreen` it is also guaranteed to be only invoked once?

Comment: yes, it a singleton, in case the results comes from util function. you can also prepere the results in the utils and import it as an array that already ready :) or make it JSON file it also can be good